# Find -> (node:1976) Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it

Tags: node.js, debugging, promise, bluebird

How to find where promise is created and not returned. I am using bluebird.

```
(node:1976) Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it
```

I know we can ignore this warning by adding `BLUEBIRD_W_FORGOTTEN_RETURN=0` in my environment. I am more interested in to find where it is coming from.

Comment: Run node with `--trace-warnings` and post the full stack trace.